# Copying formatted text with zeroclipboard

Tags: javascript, zeroclipboard

I am using zeroclipboard to copy content from a div to my clipboard. This code

```
var zc_client = new ZeroClipboard( $('#copyButton'));
zc_client.on( 'ready', function(event) {
  zc_client.on( 'copy', function(event) {
    zc_client.setData("text/html",$("#result_div").html());
  });
});

zc_client.on( 'error', function(event) {
    ZeroClipboard.destroy();
} );
```

This is working well, except the copy process doesn't copy the styles associated with the stylesheet when I paste the results into word.  On my screen, I see something like this

[image: Screencap of text on screen]

But when I click the copy button and paste in word, I see this

[image: Screencap of text in Word]

Is there a way to keep the formatting like I would if I manually selected the text and pressed CTRL C on my keyboard?

I've also tried

```
zc_client.setHTML($("#result_div").html());
zc_client.setRichText($("#result_div").html());
```

But these methods paste the text in a way that the tags appear.